# Why aren't my Virtual Mongoose types showing up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my `post` model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  image: String,
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    required: true
  },
  university: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  uniOnly: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  expiresAt: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  voteCount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  comments: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'comment'
  }],
  commenters: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  }],
  categories: [{
    type: String
  }]
});

PostSchema.virtual('commentCount').get(function () {
  return this.comments.length;
});

PostSchema.virtual('expired').get(function () {
  const now = new Date().getTime();

  return now <= this.expiresAt;
});

const Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to create a couple of virtual types:

1. `commentCount` will give the length of the array of `comments`.
2. `expired` will either flag as `true` or `false`

Here is the controller:

```
create(req, res, next) {
    const postProps = req.body;
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const expiresAt = now + 43200000;

    const { author, text, image, categories, university, uniOnly } = postProps;

    Post.create({
      author,
      text,
      image,
      categories,
      university,
      uniOnly,
      createdAt: now,
      voteCount: 0,
      expiresAt,
    })
      .then(post => res.send(post))
      .catch(next);
  },
```

Right now, using Postman I can see that the post itself is being created just fine. For some reason though, I'm not getting back anything for the virtual types, neither `commentCount` nor `expired`.

This is what I get back in response:

```
}
  "__v": 0,
  "author": "5896623ff821b14c4470cf97",
  "text": "this is ANOTHER post",
  "university": "University of Birmingham",
  "uniOnly": false,
  "createdAt": 1486306414679,
  "voteCount": 0,
  "expiresAt": 1486349614679,
  "_id": "58973c6ef24ca4828c2adae1",
  "categories": [
    "music",
    "dance"
  ],
  "commenters": [],
  "comments": []
}
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I've followed along several along courses in which I've done similar before and I'm scouring through the course code. I can't work it out though.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not using JSON.stringify in my console logs. Shouldn't it show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get virtuals serialized to json object, try `doc.toObject({ virtuals: true })` as documented here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do I use this? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Okay I've added this, thank you.

I was doing a project before with mongoose and this wasn't necessary. Why might this be?

Comment: @bloppit I guess since virtuals do not store any new things, it is not necessarily to serialize virtual properties in default behavior.

Comment: @bloppit use it at the end of the processing since the result of the `doc.toObject` is not a mongoose document type, you cannot do any further interactions with database.